# Issue on from encoding mailer ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, actionmailer, mailer

I've an issue on the from name when I send mail with the Mailer by Ruby On Rails (Rails 4.1.4).

The from name is not encoded with utf-8 when I put hook inside the mail.

Kévin GUIOT  work and return the correct name encoded. 
Kévin GUIOT [MyCompagny]  does't work and return *=?UTF-8?Q?K=C3=A9vin_GUIOT_[MyCompagny]_* .

Can u help me please ?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
class TemplateMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_mail(email, subject, content, template_mail)
    from = "Kévin GUIOT [MyCompagny] <kevin.guiot@mycompagny.com>"
    mail(to: email, subject: subject, from: from) do |format|
      format.html { render html: content.html_safe }
    end
  end
end
```

Valid from with correct encoding:

```
from = "Kévin GUIOT <kevin.guiot@mycompagny.com>"
```

Invalid from with incorrect encoding (with hook):

```
from = "Kévin GUIOT [MyCompagny] <kevin.guiot@mycompagny.com>"
```

I look my emails with Outlook and the email is sended with a windows machine.

Comment: Hi Kévin. Can you please be more specific on what you tried and what is not working? If possible please provide code samples.

Comment: Hi Holger, thanks for ur answer. I edit my post to add the code which I use.

Comment: How are you sending your emails?

Comment: Emails are sending by ActionMailer::Base, with this function:

    TemplateMailer.send_mail(u[1], objet, content, template_mail).deliver

Comment: Does this happen in development? Do you use a SMTP server for sending? Do you use something like Gmail? Does it happen in production?

Comment: It happen on development and production and yes, i use SMTP server for sending. I use Outlook to receive mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try

from = '"Kévin GUIOT [MyCompagny]" '

according to the rfc https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5321.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to top of your file

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`